# Docker image wait for postgres image to start - without Bash

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a standard Python docker image that needs to start after postgers is properly started in its standard image.

I understand that I can add this Bash command in the docker-compose file:

```
command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; npm start'
depends_on:
  - mypostgres
```

But I don't have bash installed in the standard python docker image, and I'm trying to keep the installation minimal.

**Is there a way to wait for postgres without having bash installed in my image?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a standard Python docker image that needs to start after postgres is properly started in its standard image.

You mentioned "Python docker image", but you appear to be calling `npm start`, which is a node.js application, not a Python application.

The standard Python images *do* have `bash` installed (as do the official Node images):

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:3.10 bash
root@c9bdac2e23f9:/#
```

However, just checking for the port to be available may be insufficient in any case, so really what you want is to execute a query against the database and only continue once the query is successful.

A common solution is to install the postgres cli and run `psql` in a loop, like this:

```
until psql -h $HOST -U $USER -d $DB_NAME -c 'select 1' >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  echo 'Waiting for database...'
  sleep 1
done
```

You can use environment variables or a `.pgpass` file to provide the appropriate password.

If you are building a custom image, it may be better to place this logic in your `ENTRYPOINT` script rather than embedding it in the `command` field of your `docker-compose.yaml`.

If you don't want to `psql`, you can write the same logic in Python or Node utilizing whatever Postgres bindings are available (e.g., something like `psycopg2` for Python).

---

A *better* solution is to make your application robust in the face of database failures, because this allows your application to continue running if the database is briefly unavailable during a restart.